# unable to correct the error of Unexpected token, expected ":" in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

my state variable contains an array of objects(where is each object contains username,user_DP,imageUrl, caption) which is to be rendered but while using map() to render gives an error that I am unable to resolve.

example of state variable :

```
this.state = {
      route: 'signin',
      postDetails: [...]
    };
```

and my render() looks like

```
render(){
    const {route, postDetails} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
      {
        route === 'home' ?
          <Navbar/>
            {
              postDetails.map((post,index)=>{
                return(<Post 
                        key = {index} 
                        username = {post.username} 
                        user_DP = {post.user_DP}
                        imageUrl = {post.imageUrl}
                        caption = {post.caption}
                      />);      
              })
            }
          :
          (
            route === 'signin'?
              <Signin onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}/>
              :
              <Signup onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}/>
          )
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I am getting an error like this

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ":" (44:13)

  42 |         route === 'home' ?
  43 |           <Navbar/>
> 44 |             {
     |             ^
  45 |               postDetails.map((post,index)=>{
  46 |                 return(<Post 
  47 |                         key = {index}
```

please help in removing this error it will greatly help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<Navbar />` and `map()` with `<Post>`s must be within a single node. You might use [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment) or wrap them in a `<div>` if that doesn't break your design:

> The React.Fragment component lets you return multiple elements in a render() method without creating an additional DOM element.

```
function render() {
  const { route, postDetails } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {route === "home" ? (
        <> {/* <- shorthand for <React.Fragment> */}
          <Navbar />
          {postDetails.map((post, index) => {
            return (
              <Post
                key={index}
                username={post.username}
                user_DP={post.user_DP}
                imageUrl={post.imageUrl}
                caption={post.caption}
              />
            );
          })}
        </> {/* <- shorthand for </React.Fragment> */}
      ) : route === "signin" ? (
        <Signin onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
      ) : (
        <Signup onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```